# Adding a command to break long lines into shorter ones to an ed script

Tags: newlines, ed

I frequently have long lines in my `ed` document which I would like to split into separate lines of max length. I found this command which achieves this:

```
fold -s -w80 file
```

[Split very long lines](https://superuser.com/questions/826679/split-very-long-line-of-words-into-separate-lines-of-max-length)

I can apply this command also from within ed as follows:

```
!fold -s -w80 %
```

However, when I add this command to my ed script, which comprises the following lines,

```
g/\(‘‘\|’’\)/s//"/g
g/\(“\|”\)/s//"/g
g/\(‘\|’\)/s//'/g
g/\*/s///g
g/^#.*: /s///g
g/^  */s///
g/  *$/s///
g/   */s// /g
e !uniq %
e !fold -s -w80 %
# g/^$/d
w
Q
```

I get an error. I would like to know the reason for the error and a way if circumventing it.

Comment: I'd ask for the error message, but I think I know what it is :)

Comment: Nothing happens, except that I get a ? after the script has been run.

Comment: I see this as an XY problem. What's the goal? Any solution involving tricky `ed` scripts (where the only error message is `?`) cries out for re-analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary:  The error depends on either

1. Using `#` as a comment character in a non-GNU `ed`.
2. Editing the output of a command without first saving the buffer, using GNU `ed`.

Also:

- `H` is a really useful command to put at the top of editing scripts.

---

With GNU `ed`, your editing script will run without problems when I try it on a simple file with a single line saying `hello world`.  Using the native `ed` on my OpenBSD system, I get an error, `?`.

Adding the `H` command to the top of your editing script, we enable more verbose errors.  With that addition, the OpenBSD `ed` complains about line 12 in the editing script, saying `unknown command`.

Line 12, when `H` has been added as line 1, is the command

```
# g/^$/d
```

The `#` in not a standard `ed` command, but GNU `ed` seems to treat this as a comment.  BSD `ed` doesn't:

```
$ printf '%s\n' H '# hello' Q | ed -s
?
script, line 2: unknown command
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' H '# hello' Q | ged -s
```

(no output)

So *one* reason for the error could be that you're using an `ed` that does not understand `#` as a valid command.  To circumvent it, do not use this command in your editing script.

Standard `ed` does not have a way of ignoring the command given to it (there is no "comment command").

Another reason that you may get an error is that you try to use `e !somecommand` with GNU `ed` when the buffer has been edited but not saved.

Again, with an added `H` at the top of your editing script, but now with a document that is modified by some of the commands before `e !uniq %`:

```
$ ged -s file <script
?
script, line 10: Warning: buffer modified
```

When using the `-s` option, BSD `ed` does not warn you before running `e !somecommand` with unsaved changes in the buffer.

If you edit the output of `uniq` and `fold`, you must make sure to first write the editing buffer to disk!  You need to do this because both `fold` and `uniq` act on the file on disk.

So insert `w` before them:

```
g/\(‘‘\|’’\)/s//"/g
g/\(“\|”\)/s//"/g
g/\(‘\|’\)/s//'/g
g/\*/s///g
g/^#.*: /s///g
g/^  */s///
g/  *$/s///
g/   */s// /g
w
e !uniq %
w
e !fold -s -w80 %
w
Q
```

You could also combine `uniq` and `fold` into

```
w
e ! uniq % | fold -s -w80
```

Also note that both BSD and GNU `ed` supports the non-standard `wq` in place of `w` followed by `q` or `Q`.

Comment: Wonderful answer. Thank you. FYI I am now using GNU ed 1.17. The problem thus lies in the write commands.